# Nozzle scraping prints in modified Creality Ender 5 Pro

Tags: creality-ender-5

I'm using a Creality Ender 5 Pro which is modified to produce Direct Ink Writing prints. So far the prints are fine, it's just that at higher layers, the nozzle begins to drag across the extruded material which affects the quality of the print. Also, I'm using a high infill percentage (80 %) as with 30 % the material collapses in the middle.

How should I go about in bringing the nozzle up at the higher layers? I've tried increasing the height of the Z end stop so that the nozzle would not go too far down, but it looks like it doesn't solve the issue. Should I increase the height further?

I also tried to search online regarding this issue, and found that over-extrusion is the main cause for this. However, I'm extruding at the lowest speed possible with the inks I'm using. Should I just increase the print speed?

Additionally, would adding a Z hop command in Creality slicer work?

Any suggestions are welcome, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Creality Slicer is a derivative of an old Cura version.